# Missing artifact error and The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-dependency

I start a new project in Maven and I  had some code
while searching for dependencies ,I get this error/message

"***Missing artifact com.google.common:google-collect:jar:1.0-rc1***"

[image: Missing artifact com.google.common:google-collect:jar:1.0-rc1]

**and this in the code**

[image]

how to solve it ? I found an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution : too old dependencies that already moved to other place
just search in google for the other , much newer dependency***

[image]

[image]